# Solaris-compatible password managers

Tags: password, solaris, software-rec, password-store

I am working on a Solaris machine (Solaris 11.4.26.75.4, sun4v architecture) and would like to use a password manager to centralize storing various passwords. The password manager has the following specific

Limitations / Requirements:

- compatible with Solaris
- I do not have admin rights / sudo access --> ideally portable executable or local installation
- no dnf / yum / apt / other package managers are installed
- password access and editing from command line is required
- should not be cloud-based (local storage)
- should potentially allow password access from Windows as well (non-cloud-based sync is ok)
- ideally free

I checked `KeypassXC`, but I cannot use the portable AppImage (likely due to system architecture; *"cannot execute binary file"*), nor install from source (`cmake` command is missing and no sudo rights). `Bitwarden` is cloud-based.  `gnome-keyring` and `seahorse` commands are not available. `passwd` is available, but does not fulfill the cross-platform requirement.

Of course I googled about Solaris-compatible password managers, but did not find a lot of useful info to be honest. Therefore I wanted to ask:

**Which existing password managers fulfill the above requirements and which of them do you recommend?**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more appropriate here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/